# How to search in nested object for multiple values on same field in Elasticsearch with NEST Library?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nested, nest

I have nested documents such as;

```
public sealed class CampaignIndexModel : ElasticEntity<Guid>
    {
        public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string SlugKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public string PreviewImageUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
        
        [Nested]
        public List<BadgeIndexModel> Badges { get; set; } 
    }



 public class BadgeIndexModel
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I'd like to query in nested object with multiple values. For example, I need to query which included Code property which are "AD", "NEW". All documents must have badge and their code properties must be "AD" and "NEW". The code properties can be dynamically. Actually I'd like to search list of string in the nested object's code property.

Note that the classes are auto-mapped while creating indexes.

I hope the question is clear, understandable.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

As far as I researched Elasticsearch documentations, as below, the query result returns match exactly given badges codes.

```
q.Bool(b=>b
          .Must(x=>x.
             Nested(n=>n
                .Path(p=>p.Badges)
                    .Query(qq=>qq
                         .Term(t=>t                                    
                            .Field(f=>f.Badges.First().Code.Suffix("keyword"))
                                    .Value(badge))))))
```

Then, the answer which is marked correct, returns documents which contains badge codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a little while you posted the question. But here you go -- You could do this by creating a Nested Query within which you could filter upon your list and pass this to your search method. Below method shows how this can be done. This takes the list of strings that you want to use as values for codes.

```
private static QueryContainer BuildNestedQuery(List<string> badgeCodes)
{
    // badgeCodes is your list of strings that you want to filter on
    return new QueryContainerDescriptor<CampaignIndexModel>()
        .Nested(n =>
            n.Path(c => c.Badges)
             .Query(q => q
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.Badges.FirstOrDefault().Code)
                    .Terms(badgeCodes.ToArray())
                )
             )
        )   
}
```

This QueryContainer can further be passed to the Search method of the `NEST` client like something shown below. However, please bear in mind that there could be slight changes in the way you trigger the client's search method depending on how you're doing it, but hooking it to the search method remains more or less the same as shown below.

```
// replace T with type of your choice
// client is a reference to NEST client
var result = client.Search<T>(    
    .From(0)
    .Size(20)
    .Query(q => BuildNestedQuery(badgeCodesList))
    // other methods that you want to chain go here
)
```

Comment: Sai, Thanks for response. As far as I researched, The your query result contains given badge codes in the approach.

Comment: @OfficalMesut, given your additional context as part of the update, leveraging the extension method which are available on the properties makes sense. More can be read about that here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/property-inference.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I'll take a look @Sai